# How can I find which category has the most products shipped and the net income from sales in that category?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the w3schools.com SQL tutorial Northwind database, I'm trying to display the category that has the most products shipped. Additionally, I want to display the net income from all sales in that category. I can't figure out how to take the category with the most products shipped, and use the amount of products shipped to calculate the net income of that category. This is because there are many different products that have the same CategoryID but different prices.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS categories;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orderdetails;

CREATE TABLE categories
(CategoryID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,CategoryName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,Description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO categories VALUES
(1,'Beverages','Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales'), 
(2,'Condiments','Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings'), 
(3,'Confections','Desserts, candies, and sweet breads'), 
(4,'Dairy Products','Cheeses'), 
(5,'Grains/Cereals','Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal'), 
(6,'Meat/Poultry','Prepared meats'), 
(7,'Produce','Dried fruit and bean curd'), 
(8,'Seafood','Seaweed and fish');


CREATE TABLE products
(ProductID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,ProductName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,SupplierID INT NOT NULL
,CategoryID INT NOT NULL
,Unit VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
,Price DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO products VALUES
( 1,"Chais",1,1,"10 boxes x 20 bags"                ,'18'), 
( 2,"Chang",1,1,"24 - 12 oz bottles"                ,'19'), 
( 3,"Aniseed Syrup",1,2,"12 - 550 ml bottles"           ,'10'), 
( 4,"Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",2,2,"48 - 6 oz jars"     ,'22'), 
( 5,"Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix",2,2,"36 boxes"         ,'21.35'), 
( 6,"Grandma's Boysenberry Spread",3,2,"12 - 8 oz jars"     ,'25'), 
( 7,"Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears",3,7,"12 - 1 lb pkgs." ,'30'), 
( 8,"Northwoods Cranberry Sauce",3,2,"12 - 12 oz jars"      ,'40'), 
( 9,"Mishi Kobe Niku",4,6,"18 - 500 g pkgs."            ,'97'), 
(10,"Ikura",4,8,"12 - 200 ml jars"              ,'31'), 
(11,"Queso Cabrales",5,4,"1 kg pkg."                ,'21'), 
(12,"Queso Manchego La Pastora",5,4,"10 - 500 g pkgs."      ,'38'), 
(13,"Konbu",6,8,"2 kg box"                  ,'6'), 
(14,"Tofu",6,7,"40 - 100 g pkgs."               ,'23.25'), 
(15,"Genen Shouyu",6,2,"24 - 250 ml bottles"            ,'15.5'), 
(16,"Pavlova",7,3,"32 - 500 g boxes"                ,'17.45'), 
(17,"Alice Mutton",7,6,"20 - 1 kg tins"             ,'39'), 
(18,"Carnarvon Tigers",7,8,"16 kg pkg."             ,'62.5'), 
(19,"Teatime Chocolate Biscuits",8,3,"10 boxes x 12 pieces" ,'9.2'), 
(20,"Sir Rodney's Marmalade",8,3,"30 gift boxes"        ,'81'), 
(21,"Sir Rodney's Scones",8,3,"24 pkgs. x 4 pieces"     ,'10'), 
(22,"Gustaf's Knäckebröd",9,5,"24 - 500 g pkgs."        ,'21'), 
(23,"Tunnbröd",9,5,"12 - 250 g pkgs.",'9'), 
(24,"Guaraná Fantástica",10,1,"12 - 355 ml cans",'4.5'), 
(25,"NuNuCa Nuß-Nougat-Creme",11,3,"20 - 450 g glasses",'14'), 
(26,"Gumbär Gummibärchen",11,3,"100 - 250 g bags",'31.23'), 
(27,"Schoggi Schokolade",11,3,"100 - 100 g pieces",'43.9'), 
(28,"Rössle Sauerkraut",12,7,"25 - 825 g cans",'45.6'), 
(29,"Thüringer Rostbratwurst",12,6,"50 bags x 30 sausgs.",'123.79'), 
(30,"Nord-Ost Matjeshering",13,8,"10 - 200 g glasses",'25.89'), 
(31,"Gorgonzola Telino",14,4,"12 - 100 g pkgs",'12.5'), 
(32,"Mascarpone Fabioli",14,4,"24 - 200 g pkgs.",'32'), 
(33,"Geitost",15,4,"500 g",'2.5'), 
(34,"Sasquatch Ale",16,1,"24 - 12 oz bottles",'14'), 
(35,"Steeleye Stout",16,1,"24 - 12 oz bottles",'18'), 
(36,"Inlagd Sill",17,8,"24 - 250 g jars",'19'), 
(37,"Gravad lax",17,8,"12 - 500 g pkgs.",'26'), 
(38,"Côte de Blaye",18,1,"12 - 75 cl bottles",'263.5'), 
(39,"Chartreuse verte",18,1,"750 cc per bottle",'18'), 
(40,"Boston Crab Meat",19,8,"24 - 4 oz tins",'18.4'), 
(41,"Jack's New England Clam Chowder",19,8,"12 - 12 oz cans",'9.65'), 
(42,"Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee",20,5,"32 - 1 kg pkgs.",'14'), 
(43,"Ipoh Coffee",20,1,"16 - 500 g tins",'46'), 
(44,"Gula Malacca",20,2,"20 - 2 kg bags",'19.45'), 
(45,"Røgede sild",21,8,"1k pkg.",'9.5'), 
(46,"Spegesild",21,8,"4 - 450 g glasses",'12'), 
(47,"Zaanse koeken",22,3,"10 - 4 oz boxes",'9.5'), 
(48,"Chocolade",22,3,"10 pkgs.",'12.75'), 
(49,"Maxilaku",23,3,"24 - 50 g pkgs.",'20'), 
(50,"Valkoinen suklaa",23,3,"12 - 100 g bars",'16.25'),
(51,"Manjimup Dried Apples",24,7,"50 - 300 g pkgs.",'53'),
(52,"Filo Mix",24,5,"16 - 2 kg boxes",'7'), 
(53,"Perth Pasties",24,6,"48 pieces",'32.8'), 
(54,"Tourtière",25,6,"16 pies",'7.45'), 
(55,"Pâté chinois",25,6,"24 boxes x 2 pies",'24'), 
(56,"Gnocchi di nonna Alice",26,5,"24 - 250 g pkgs.",'38'), 
(57,"Ravioli Angelo",26,5,"24 - 250 g pkgs.",'19.5'), 
(58,"Escargots de Bourgogne",27,8,"24 pieces",'13.25'), 
(59,"Raclette Courdavault",28,4,"5 kg pkg.",'55'), 
(60,"Camembert Pierrot",28,4,"15 - 300 g rounds",'34'),
(61,"Sirop d'érable",29,2,"24 - 500 ml bottles",'28.5'), 
(62,"Tarte au sucre",29,3,"48 pies",'49.3'), 
(63,"Vegie-spread",7,2,"15 - 625 g jars",'43.9'), 
(64,"Wimmers gute Semmelknödel",12,5,"20 bags x 4 pieces",'33.25'), 
(65,"Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce",2,2,"32 - 8 oz bottles",'21.05'), 
(66,"Louisiana Hot Spiced Okra",2,2,"24 - 8 oz jars",'17'), 
(67,"Laughing Lumberjack Lager",16,1,"24 - 12 oz bottles",'14'), 
(68,"Scottish Longbreads",8,3,"10 boxes x 8 pieces",'12.5'), 
(69,"Gudbrandsdalsost",15,4,"10 kg pkg.",'36'), 
(70,"Outback Lager",7,1,"24 - 355 ml bottles",'15'), 
(71,"Fløtemysost",15,4,"10 - 500 g pkgs.",'21.5'), 
(72,"Mozzarella di Giovanni",14,4,"24 - 200 g pkgs.",'34.8'), 
(73,"Röd Kaviar",17,8,"24 - 150 g jars",'15'), 
(74,"Longlife Tofu",4,7,"5 kg pkg.",'10'), 
(75,"Rhönbräu Klosterbier",12,1,"24 - 0.5 l bottles",'7.75'), 
(76,"Lakkalikööri",23,1,"500 ml",'18'), 
(77,"Original Frankfurter grüne Soße",12,2,"12 boxes",'13'); 
   
CREATE TABLE orderdetails
(OrderDetailID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,OrderID INT NOT NULL
,ProductID INT NOT NULL
,Quantity INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO orderdetails VALUES
(1,10248,11,12),
(2,10248,42,10 ),
(  3,10248,72, 5 ),
(  4,10249,14, 9 ),
(  5,10249,51,40 ),
(  6,10250,41,10 ),
(  7,10250,51,35 ),
(  8,10250,65,15 ),
(  9,10251,22, 6 ),
( 10,10251,57,15 ),
( 11,10251,65,20 ),
( 12,10252,20,40 ),
( 13,10252,33,25 ),
( 14,10252,60,40 ),
( 15,10253,31,20 ),
( 16,10253,39,42 ),
( 17,10253,49,40 ),
( 18,10254,24,15 ),
( 19,10254,55,21 ),
( 20,10254,74,21 ),
( 21,10255, 2,20 ),
( 22,10255,16,35 ),
( 23,10255,36,25 ),
( 24,10255,59,30 ),
( 25,10256,53,15 ),
( 26,10256,77,12 ),
( 27,10257,27,25 ),
( 28,10257,39, 6 ),
( 29,10257,77,15 ),
( 30,10258, 2,50 ),
( 31,10258, 5,65 ),
( 32,10258,32, 6 ),
( 33,10259,21,10 ),
( 34,10259,37, 1 ),
( 35,10260,41,16 ),
( 36,10260,57, 50 ),
( 37,10260,62, 15 ),
( 38,10260,70, 21 ),
( 39,10261,21, 20 ),
( 40,10261,35, 20 ),
( 41,10262, 5, 12 ),
( 42,10262, 7, 15 ),
( 43,10262,56,  2 ),
( 44,10263,16, 60 ),
( 45,10263,24, 28 ),
( 46,10263,30, 60 ),
( 47,10263,74, 36 ),
( 48,10264, 2, 35 ),
( 49,10264,41, 25 ),
( 50,10265,17, 30 ),
( 51,10265,70, 20 ),
( 52,10266,12, 12 ),
( 53,10267,40, 50 ),
( 54,10267,59, 70 ),
( 55,10267,76, 15 ),
( 56,10268,29, 10 ),
( 57,10268,72,  4 ),
( 58,10269,33, 60 ),
( 59,10269,72, 20 ),
( 60,10270,36, 30 ),
( 61,10270,43, 25 ),
( 62,10271,33, 24 ),
( 63,10272,20,  6 ),
( 64,10272,31, 40 ),
( 65,10272,72, 24 ),
( 66,10273,10, 24 ),
( 67,10273,31, 15 ),
( 68,10273,33, 20 ),
( 69,10273,40, 60 ),
( 70,10273,76, 33 ),
( 71,10274,71, 20 ),
( 72,10274,72,  7 ),
( 73,10275,24, 12 ),
( 74,10275,59,  6 ),
( 75,10276,10, 15 ),
( 76,10276,13, 10 ),
( 77,10277,28, 20 ),
( 78,10277,62, 12 ),
( 79,10278,44, 16 ),
( 80,10278,59, 15 ),
( 81,10278,63,  8 ),
( 82,10278,73, 25 ),
( 83,10279,17, 15 ),
( 84,10280,24, 12 ),
( 85,10280,55, 20 ),
( 86,10280,75, 30 ),
( 87,10281,19,  1 ),
( 88,10281,24,  6 ),
( 89,10281,35,  4 ),
( 90,10282,30,  6 ),
( 91,10282,57,  2 ),
( 92,10283,15, 20 ),
( 93,10283,19, 18 ),
( 94,10283,60, 35 ),
( 95,10283,72,  3 ),
( 96,10284,27, 15 ),
( 97,10284,44, 21 ),
( 98,10284,60, 20 ),
( 99,10284,67,  5 ),
(100,10285, 1, 45 ),
(101,10285,40, 40 ),
(102,10285,53, 36 ),
(103,10286,35,100 ),
(104,10286,62, 40 ),
(105,10287,16, 40 ),
(106,10287,34, 20 ),
(107,10287,46, 15 ),
(108,10288,54, 10 ),
(109,10288,68,  3 ),
(110,10289, 3, 30 ),
(111,10289,64,  9 ),
(112,10290, 5, 20 ),
(113,10290,29, 15 ),
(114,10290,49, 15 ),
(115,10290,77, 10 ),
(116,10291,13, 20 ),
(117,10291,44, 24 ),
(118,10291,51, 2 ),
(119,10292,20, 20 ),
(120,10293,18, 12 ),
(121,10293,24, 10 ),
(122,10293,63,  5 ),
(123,10293,75,  6 ),
(124,10294, 1, 18 ),
(125,10294,17, 15 ),
(126,10294,43, 15 ),
(127,10294,60, 21 ),
(128,10294,75,  6 ),
(129,10295,56,  4 ),
(130,10296,11, 12 ),
(131,10296,16, 30 ),
(132,10296,69, 15 ),
(133,10297,39, 60 ),
(134,10297,72, 20 ),
(135,10298, 2, 40 ),
(136,10298,36, 40 ),
(137,10298,59, 30 ),
(138,10298,62, 15 ),
(139,10299,19, 15 ),
(140,10299,70, 20 ),
(141,10300,66, 30 ),
(142,10300,68, 20 ),
(143,10301,40, 10 ),
(144,10301,56, 20 ),
(145,10302,17, 40 ),
(146,10302,28, 28 ),
(147,10302,43, 12 ),
(148,10303,40, 40 ),
(149,10303,65, 30 ),
(150,10303,68, 15 ),
(151,10304,49, 30 ),
(152,10304,59, 10 ),
(153,10304,71,  2 ),
(154,10305,18, 25 ),
(155,10305,29, 25 ),
(156,10305,39, 30 ),
(157,10306,30, 10 ),
(158,10306,53, 10 ),
(159,10306,54,  5 ),
(160,10307,62, 10 ),
(161,10307,68,  3 ),
(162,10308,69,  1 ),
(163,10308,70,  5 ),
(164,10309, 4, 20 ),
(165,10309, 6, 30 ),
(166,10309,42,  2 ),
(167,10309,43, 20 ),
(168,10309,71,  3 ),
(169,10310,16, 10 ),
(170,10310,62,  5 ),
(171,10311,42,  6 ),
(172,10311,69,  7 ),
(173,10312,28,  4 ),
(174,10312,43, 24 ),
(175,10312,53, 20 ),
(176,10312,75, 10 ),
(177,10313,36, 12 ),
(178,10314,32, 40 ),
(179,10314,58, 30 ),
(180,10314,62, 25 ),
(181,10315,34, 14 ),
(182,10315,70, 30 ),
(183,10316,41, 10 ),
(184,10316,62, 70 ),
(185,10317, 1, 20 ),
(186,10318,41, 20 ),
(187,10318,76,  6 ),
(188,10319,17,  8 ),
(189,10319,28, 14 ),
(190,10319,76, 30 ),
(191,10320,71, 30 ),
(192,10321,35, 10 ),
(193,10322,52, 20 ),
(194,10323,15,  5 ),
(195,10323,25,  4 ),
(196,10323,39,  4 ),
(197,10324,16, 21 ),
(198,10324,35, 70 ),
(199,10324,46, 30 ),
(200,10324,59, 40 ),
(201,10324,63, 80 ),
(202,10325, 6,  6 ),
(203,10325,13, 12 ),
(204,10325,14,  9 ),
(205,10325,31,  4 ),
(206,10325,72, 40 ),
(207,10326, 4, 24 ),
(208,10326,57, 16 ),
(209,10326,75, 50 ),
(210,10327, 2, 25 ),
(211,10327,11, 50 ),
(212,10327,30, 35 ),
(213,10327,58, 30 ),
(214,10328,59,  9 ),
(215,10328,65, 40 ),
(216,10328,68, 10 ),
(217,10329,19, 10 ),
(218,10329,30,  8 ),
(219,10329,38, 20 ),
(220,10329,56, 12 ),
(221,10330,26, 50 ),
(222,10330,72, 25 ),
(223,10331,54, 15 ),
(224,10332,18, 40 ),
(225,10332,42, 10 ),
(226,10332,47, 16 ),
(227,10333,14, 10 ),
(228,10333,21, 10 ),
(229,10333,71, 40 ),
(230,10334,52,  8 ),
(231,10334,68, 10 ),
(232,10335, 2,  7 ),
(233,10335,31, 25 ),
(234,10335,32,  6 ),
(235,10335,51, 48 ),
(236,10336, 4, 18 ),
(237,10337,23, 40 ),
(238,10337,26, 24 ),
(239,10337,36, 20 ),
(240,10337,37, 28 ),
(241,10337,72, 25 ),
(242,10338,17, 20 ),
(243,10338,30, 15 ),
(244,10339, 4, 10 ),
(245,10339,17, 70 ),
(246,10339,62, 28 ),
(247,10340,18, 20 ),
(248,10340,41, 12 ),
(249,10340,43, 40 ),
(250,10341,33,  8 ),
(251,10341,59,  9 ),
(252,10342, 2, 24 ),
(253,10342,31, 56 ),
(254,10342,36, 40 ),
(255,10342,55, 40 ),
(256,10343,64, 50 ),
(257,10343,68,  4 ),
(258,10343,76, 15 ),
(259,10344, 4, 35 ),
(260,10344, 8, 70 ),
(261,10345, 8, 70 ),
(262,10345,19, 80 ),
(263,10345,42,  9 ),
(264,10346,17, 36 ),
(265,10346,56, 20 ),
(266,10347,25, 10 ),
(267,10347,39, 50 ),
(268,10347,40,  4 ),
(269,10347,75,  6 ),
(270,10348, 1, 15 ),
(271,10348,23, 25 ),
(272,10349,54, 24 ),
(273,10350,50, 15 ),
(274,10350,69, 18 ),
(275,10351,38, 20 ),
(276,10351,41, 13 ),
(277,10351,44, 77 ),
(278,10351,65, 10 ),
(279,10352,24, 10 ),
(280,10352,54, 20 ),
(281,10353,11, 12 ),
(282,10353,38, 50 ),
(283,10354, 1, 12 ),
(284,10354,29,  4 ),
(285,10355,24, 25 ),
(286,10355,57, 25 ),
(287,10356,31, 30 ),
(288,10356,55, 12 ),
(289,10356,69, 20 ),
(290,10357,10, 30 ),
(291,10357,26, 16 ),
(292,10357,60,  8 ),
(293,10358,24, 10 ),
(294,10358,34, 10 ),
(295,10358,36, 20 ),
(296,10359,16, 56 ),
(297,10359,31, 70 ),
(298,10359,60, 80 ),
(299,10360,28, 30 ),
(300,10360,29, 35 ),
(301,10360,38, 10 ),
(302,10360,49, 35 ),
(303,10360,54, 28 ),
(304,10361,39, 54 ),
(305,10361,60, 55 ),
(306,10362,25, 50 ),
(307,10362,51, 20 ),
(308,10362,54, 24 ),
(309,10363,31, 20 ),
(310,10363,75, 12 ),
(311,10363,76, 12 ),
(312,10364,69, 30 ),
(313,10364,71,  5 ),
(314,10365,11, 24 ),
(315,10366,65,  5 ),
(316,10366,77,  5 ),
(317,10367,34, 36 ),
(318,10367,54, 18 ),
(319,10367,65, 15 ),
(320,10367,77,  7 ),
(321,10368,21,  5 ),
(322,10368,28, 13 ),
(323,10368,57, 25 ),
(324,10368,64, 35 ),
(325,10369,29, 20 ),
(326,10369,56, 18 ),
(327,10370, 1, 15 ),
(328,10370,64, 30 ),
(329,10370,74, 20 ),
(330,10371,36,  6 ),
(331,10372,20,12 ),
(332,10372,38,40 ),
(333,10372,60,70 ),
(334,10372,72,42 ),
(335,10373,58,80 ),
(336,10373,71,50 ),
(337,10374,31,30 ),
(338,10374,58,15 ),
(339,10375,14,15 ),
(340,10375,54,10 ),
(341,10376,31,42 ),
(342,10377,28,20 ),
(343,10377,39,20 ),
(344,10378,71,6 ),
(345,10379,41,8 ),
(346,10379,63,16 ),
(347,10379,65,20 ),
(348,10380,30,18 ),
(349,10380,53,20 ),
(350,10380,60,6 ),
(351,10380,70,30 ),
(352,10381,74,14 ),
(353,10382,5,32 ),
(354,10382,18,9 ),
(355,10382,29,14 ),
(356,10382,33,60 ),
(357,10382,74,50 ),
(358,10383,13,20 ),
(359,10383,50,15 ),
(360,10383,56,20 ),
(361,10384,20,28 ),
(362,10384,60,15 ),
(363,10385,7,10 ),
(364,10385,60,20 ),
(365,10385,68,8 ),
(366,10386,24,15 ),
(367,10386,34,10 ),
(368,10387,24,15 ),
(369,10387,28,6 ),
(370,10387,59,12 ),
(371,10387,71,15 ),
(372,10388,45,15 ),
(373,10388,52,20 ),
(374,10388,53,40 ),
(375,10389,10,16 ),
(376,10389,55,15 ),
(377,10389,62,20 ),
(378,10389,70,30 ),
(379,10390,31,60 ),
(380,10390,35,40 ),
(381,10390,46,45 ),
(382,10390,72,24 ),
(383,10391,13,18 ),
(384,10392,69,50 ),
(385,10393, 2,25 ),
(386,10393,14,42 ),
(387,10393,25,7 ),
(388,10393,26,70 ),
(389,10393,31,32 ),
(390,10394,13,10 ),
(391,10394,62,10 ),
(392,10395,46,28 ),
(393,10395,53,70 ),
(394,10395,69,8 ),
(395,10396,23,40 ),
(396,10396,71,60 ),
(397,10396,72,21 ),
(398,10397,21,10 ),
(399,10397,51,18 ),
(400,10398,35,30 ),
(401,10398,55,120 ),
(402,10399,68,60 ),
(403,10399,71,30 ),
(404,10399,76,35 ),
(405,10399,77,14 ),
(406,10400,29,21 ),
(407,10400,35,35 ),
(408,10400,49,30 ),
(409,10401,30,18 ),
(410,10401,56,70 ),
(411,10401,65,20 ),
(412,10401,71,60 ),
(413,10402,23,60 ),
(414,10402,63,65 ),
(415,10403,16,21 ),
(416,10403,48,70 ),
(417,10404,26,30 ),
(418,10404,42,40 ),
(419,10404,49,30 ),
(420,10405, 3,50 ),
(421,10406, 1,10 ),
(422,10406,21,30 ),
(423,10406,28,42 ),
(424,10406,36,5 ),
(425,10406,40,2 ),
(426,10407,11,30 ),
(427,10407,69,15 ),
(428,10407,71,15 ),
(429,10408,37,10 ),
(430,10408,54,6 ),
(431,10408,62,35 ),
(432,10409,14,12 ),
(433,10409,21,12 ),
(434,10410,33,49 ),
(435,10410,59,16 ),
(436,10411,41,25 ),
(437,10411,44,40 ),
(438,10411,59,9 ),
(439,10412,14,20 ),
(440,10413, 1,24 ),
(441,10413,62,40 ),
(442,10413,76,14 ),
(443,10414,19,18 ),
(444,10414,33,50 ),
(445,10415,17,2 ),
(446,10415,33,20 ),
(447,10416,19,20 ),
(448,10416,53,10 ),
(449,10416,57,20 ),
(450,10417,38,50 ),
(451,10417,46,2 ),
(452,10417,68,36 ),
(453,10417,77,35 ),
(454,10418, 2,60 ),
(455,10418,47,55 ),
(456,10418,61,16 ),
(457,10418,74,15 ),
(458,10419,60,60 ),
(459,10419,69,20 ),
(460,10420, 9,20 ),
(461,10420,13,2 ),
(462,10420,70,8 ),
(463,10420,73,20 ),
(464,10421,19,4 ),
(465,10421,26,30 ),
(466,10421,53,15 ),
(467,10421,77,10 ),
(468,10422,26,2 ),
(469,10423,31,14 ),
(470,10423,59,20 ),
(471,10424,35,60 ),
(472,10424,38,49 ),
(473,10424,68,30 ),
(474,10425,55,10 ),
(475,10425,76,20 ),
(476,10426,56,5 ),
(477,10426,64,7 ),
(478,10427,14,35 ),
(479,10428,46,20 ),
(480,10429,50,40 ),
(481,10429,63,35 ),
(482,10430,17,45 ),
(483,10430,21,50 ),
(484,10430,56,30 ),
(485,10430,59,70 ),
(486,10431,17,50 ),
(487,10431,40,50 ),
(488,10431,47,30 ),
(489,10432,26,10 ),
(490,10432,54,40 ),
(491,10433,56,28 ),
(492,10434,11,6 ),
(493,10434,76,18 ),
(494,10435,2,10 ),
(495,10435,22,12 ),
(496,10435,72,10 ),
(497,10436,46,5 ),
(498,10436,56,40 ),
(499,10436,64,30 ),
(500,10436,75,24 ),
(501,10437,53,15 ),
(502,10438,19,15 ),
(503,10438,34,20 ),
(504,10438,57,15 ),
(505,10439,12,15 ),
(506,10439,16,16 ),
(507,10439,64,6 ),
(508,10439,74,30 ),
(509,10440, 2,45 ),
(510,10440,16,49 ),
(511,10440,29,24 ),
(512,10440,61,90 ),
(513,10441,27,50 ),
(514,10442,11,30 ),
(515,10442,54,80 ),
(516,10442,66,60 ),
(517,10443,11,6 ),
(518,10443,28,12);
```

Database: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

So far, I'm summing the quantity of each order in OrderDetails, joining the Categories, OrderDetails and Products tables and grouping the results by CategoryID. Then, I thought I would order the table descending by the number of products shipped, select the category with the most products shipped and calculate the category's net income. I now realize this is the wrong way to approach this, because there are many different products under the same CategoryID that have different prices. I'm new to SQL, and I've done some digging around on Google to try and figure this out, but to no avail.

So far I've come up with this:

```sql
SELECT ct.CategoryID, ct.CategoryName, SUM(odt.Quantity) AS ProductsShipped
FROM Categories AS ct
INNER JOIN Products AS p ON p.CategoryID = ct.CategoryID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS odt ON odt.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY ct.CategoryID
ORDER BY ProductsShipped DESC;
```

The above code displays:

```
CategoryID            CategoryName          ProductsShipped
4                      Dairy Products            2601
1                      Beverages                 2289
3                      Confections               2110
8                      Seafood                   1445
2                      Condiments                1383
6                      Meat/Poultry              1288
5                      Grains/Cereals            912
7                      Produce                   715
```

I feel like I'm somewhat on the right track, but I can feel that I need to retrace a little bit and implement something in the code before my GROUP BY command in order to calculate the net income of that category. Problem is I can't figure out what to code.

EDIT: Also, how can I select only the top entry in my table? I only want to display Dairy Products as it has the most products shipped.

Comment: You probably want something like `SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity * Products.Price) AS Income`. Then you need to subquery all that to get the category with the highest income

Comment: Incidentally, Northwind has many issues. Chiefly, in your case: what happens if you change the price of a product? The `OrderDetail` has no info on `PriceSoldAt`. Also, don't use column names that you need to quote with brackets. And you don't need the brackets around joins.

Comment: I have added an answer, let me know if it produces desired behavior or not

Comment: @Vantablack, yes, you will join the category table and the resultant table from the subquery

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts like that, that's no good ;) Better rollback the edit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my original code, I simply added a sum command in my original select statement to calculate the income of a category through multiplying product price by quantity in an order. I checked that the resulting table is correct through manual calculation. No need for a sub query.

```
SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity * Products.Price)
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you get the income for each product and category and then based on that you find total income for that category and you do this with the help of subquery, then you join this resultant table with the category table and with the help of group by you find the product count and total income for each category, below is the sql query for more indepth understanding

```
SELECT ct.CategoryID 
     , ct.CategoryName
     , SUM(pdd.ProductQuantityShipped) AS ProductsShipped
     , SUM(pdd.product_income) AS CategoryIncome 
  FROM Categories AS ct 
  INNER JOIN 
     ( SELECT pd.ProductID AS productId
            , pd.CategoryID
            , SUM(odt.Quantity) AS ProductQuantityShipped
            , SUM(pd.Price * odt.Quantity) AS product_income 
         FROM Products AS pd 
         INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS odt 
           ON pd.ProductID = odt.ProductID 
        GROUP 
           BY pd.ProductID
            , pd.CategoryID
     ) AS pdd
    ON ct.CategoryID = pdd.CategoryID
 GROUP 
    BY ct.CategoryID
     , ct.CategoryName
 ORDER 
    BY SUM(pdd.ProductQuantityShipped) DESC;
```

I am assuming you are using mysql as you mentioned it in question tags , you can use 'limit' and 'offset' for getting the desired range of output i.e 'LIMIT n' is used for limiting the row count to 'n' in output and 'OFFSET n' is used for skipping first 'n' rows. see the below updated code for getting the output for category having highest product shipped

```
SELECT ct.CategoryID 
     , ct.CategoryName
     , SUM(pdd.ProductQuantityShipped) AS ProductsShipped
     , SUM(pdd.product_income) AS CategoryIncome 
  FROM Categories AS ct 
  INNER JOIN 
     ( SELECT pd.ProductID AS productId
            , pd.CategoryID
            , SUM(odt.Quantity) AS ProductQuantityShipped
            , SUM(pd.Price * odt.Quantity) AS product_income 
         FROM Products AS pd 
         INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS odt 
           ON pd.ProductID = odt.ProductID 
        GROUP 
           BY pd.ProductID
            , pd.CategoryID
     ) AS pdd
    ON ct.CategoryID = pdd.CategoryID
 GROUP 
    BY ct.CategoryID
     , ct.CategoryName
 ORDER 
    BY SUM(pdd.ProductQuantityShipped) DESC
 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

If you want to run it on mssql server that is used by w3-school that you mentioned, then you need to use 'TOP' for limiting the row count

```
SELECT TOP 1
       ct.CategoryID 
     , ct.CategoryName
     , SUM(pdd.ProductQuantityShipped) AS ProductsShipped
     , SUM(pdd.product_income) AS CategoryIncome 
  FROM Categories AS ct 
  INNER JOIN 
     ( SELECT pd.ProductID AS productId
            , pd.CategoryID
            , SUM(odt.Quantity) AS ProductQuantityShipped
            , SUM(pd.Price * odt.Quantity) AS product_income 
         FROM Products AS pd 
         INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS odt 
           ON pd.ProductID = odt.ProductID 
        GROUP 
           BY pd.ProductID
            , pd.CategoryID
     ) AS pdd
    ON ct.CategoryID = pdd.CategoryID
 GROUP 
    BY ct.CategoryID
     , ct.CategoryName
 ORDER 
    BY SUM(pdd.ProductQuantityShipped) DESC;
```

Comment: @Vantablack 'ct.CategoryID' is just a way to access table through some alias name, i.e here I am referring Category with ct as alias, Usually It is for cases where writing long table name sometimes becomes cumbersome and it also helps if you are involving same table multiple times in a query.

Comment: @Vantablack You can run above query to check if it producing what is desired, let me know if it is not producing the correct output.

Comment: @Vantablack, that was because I assumed you wanted to count total orders, since you want the sum of product quantities, I have updated the query, it should be correct now and added a new query for getting the top category in mysql

Comment: @Vantablack glad to be of help:>  top is used in mssql server and limit is used in mysql, postgresql server to limit the rows. so just wanted to let you know that always be sure which database are you using if something expected doesn't work.